# Exception Handling in GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, exception

I have created a GUI in java, which holds a number of JButtons. I want to include some exception handling so that if a particular button is clicked twice or directly after each other, a message pops up to say that this command is not allowed. Which type of Exception would you suggest I use?

Regards.

Comment: Java only has one "type" of exception handling. You either throw, you catch, or you ignore. Can you expand on that a little?

Comment: Better disable that button so that use can not click it again.

Comment: Simply use `getClickCount()`. If it's bigger than 2, disable the clicking. I don't understand why you need an *exception* here.

Comment: I understand I have to use try and catch. But what do I put in the bracket after catch is what I mean.

Comment: @Maroun, I need the exception so that when a particular button is clicked in succession, a messaged will be displayed to the user to say "invalid command".

Comment: I think you need to get a book on Java first.  You are not understanding some basic concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throwing an exception from a method like `actionPerformed` is forbidden by the langage semantic. Even if it would have been authorized, what do you think the main event handling thread will be able to do with such an exception ?

What you need is to re-think the way your interface works. For example, if an action is forbidden then your interface must show it, by disabling objects for example. It is much more ergonomic to not let the user be able to click on a button than to let it click and send him some feedback that his action was bad.

In more complex scenarii you just have to let some modal dialog appears to inform the user that what he asked is impossible for the moment. This may be the result of some exception thrown during your event handler, but you catch it not throw it:

```
... actionPerformed(...) {
  if (someConditionOccured) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(...);
  } else {
    // do what you want on normal condition
  }
```

Now the that could be something like :

```
... actionPerformed(...) {
  try {
    // something
  } catch (...) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(...);
  }
```

You can use any other suitable dialog.

Comment: I never intended to use throw. I always knew I would use try and catch. My question was, what do I actually enter in the bracket after catch, that would be suitable to check if a particular JButton was clicked in succession.

Comment: So why talking about exception handling ? Your double-clicked condition can be tested without exception handling ? Did I missed a point ?

Comment: Yes look at my edited answer, I gave you two examples : one that simply test some condition with an if and the other one that uses an exceptional condition...

Comment: Yeah, but what exactly goes in the bracket that says (someConditionOccured) that would check if a JButton is clicked twice in a row? I understand the if statement, I just need the function that would check for my condition which is a JButton being clicked twice in a row.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you attach a listener to each button, to perform an action when the button is clicked.

In that listener, before you perform the action that belongs to that button, do some validation:

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) { 
    if (e.getSource() == myNotAllowedToClickButton) {
        return;
    }

    // code that does stuff
}
```

Even better, make sure the user cannot click the button, by disabling it (`myButton.setEnabled(false);`).

Comment: Throwing an exception from `actionPerformed` is forbidden. You can't throw any exception because the signature of the method don't specify such. Even if it was authorized, what do you think the main event handling thread will do with it ?

Comment: Very true, excuse me. Answer fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You simply cannot use try/catch here because clicking a button twice is not an exceptional condition.  No exception will be generated simply by the action alone.  Anything you do in your code after the user clicks may cause exceptions, but that's on you.

What you want to do here is determine if the user has clicked more than once using getClickCount() on the action event.  Alternatively, you can disable the button at the beginning of your action listener - perform whatever actions you need to - and then enable the button again at the end of the action.

If you need anything more complex than this you need to re-design your application as you will likely end up running into concurrency problems.

Answer (score 0):

- Add a common action listener to all buttons.
- Maintain a fixed size stack to store clicked buttons.
- On a click on any button

  - Push the clicked button in the stack on every click (oldest item should be removed, if required).
  - Check the stack for invalid click pattern and take required action.

Size of stack should be equal to maximum size of click patterns, you will use.